# Running ipython from command line - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'

Tags: python, error-handling, ipython, modulenotfounderror, prompt-toolkit

I am trying to run iPython from the command line and get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'prompt_toolkit.formatted_text'
```

Because of that I read some posts where it was advised to install specific versions of prompt-toolkit and ipython which I did but got the errors below:

```
pip install prompt-toolkit==1.0.14


ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
jupyter-console 6.4.0 requires prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0, but you have prompt-toolkit 1.0.14 which is incompatible.
ipython 6.5.0 requires prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.15, but you have prompt-toolkit 1.0.14 which is incompatible.


pip install ipython==5.2.0

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
jupyter-console 6.4.0 requires prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0, but you have prompt-toolkit 1.0.14 which is incompatible.
```

But still I get the `ModuleNotFoundError` from above.

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance!